# Android Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

Tags: android, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting following error when trying to run my app today.It was working yesterday. I have google a lot and no solution work for me. Please help me. Without modifying the app why this issue happened.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/util/MapCollections$ArrayIterator.class

Answer (score 0):

Check your gradle file, its because you have multiple dependency configured as your log is saying every thing.